# add SVGs inside an SVG programmatically

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I need to add SVG objects to specific locations inside an SVG object that's appended to the DOM.

But whenever I do that I see nothing rendered on the screen. I can see the SVG objects are added (in Elements tab of DevTools) but they're not rendered. They're pure SVG (not wrapped around an HTML element like a DIV).

I've tried loading SVGs with ajax and adding them, tried to do with [Snap](http://snapsvg.io/), tried to have these elements inside a `<defs>` tag, find them with Snap and then add them to the main Snap object. Nothing seems to work. The objects are always added but not rendered.

Is that even possible?

The SVG

```
<svg width="400" height="300" style="background: gray">
    <defs>
        <circle id="redc" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill: red" />
        <circle id="yelc" cx="40" cy="40" r="40" style="fill: yellow" />
    </defs>
    <circle id="bluc" cx="200" cy="200" r="50" style="fill: blue" />
</svg>
```

JavaScript

```
const s = Snap("#root");

Snap.load('images/all.svg', function(data){
    var all = data;

    // append the all.svg node. cool
    s.append( all.node );

    // get the red circle definition
    var redc = all.select('#redc');

    s.append(redc.node); // doesn't work
});
```

with foreign object:

```
Snap.load('images/all.svg', function(data){
    var all = data;

    // append the all.svg node. cool
    s.append( all.node );

    // get the red circle definition
    var redc = all.select('#redc');

    // foreign object
    var foreign = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"foreignObject");
    foreign.setAttribute('width', 500);
foreign.setAttribute('height', 150);
    foreign.appendChild(redc);

    // add the foreign object - doesn't work
    s.append( foreign );
});
```

Comment: Sure it's possible but without seeing your code we can't tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @RobertLongson just added some code, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're appending the circle outside of the `<svg>` tree i.e. directly under #root which is probably some kind of HTML element such as a `<div>`

The foreignObject problem is basically the same. Not sure why you're trying to add a circle as a child of a foreignObject (that won't work as you'd need an svg element to be its parent). I've used an html element instead.

```js
const s = Snap("#root");

var svg = '<svg width="400" height="300" style="background: gray"><defs><circle id="redc" cx="50" cy="50" r="50" style="fill: red" /><circle id="yelc" cx="40" cy="40" r="40" style="fill: yellow" /></defs><circle id="bluc" cx="200" cy="200" r="50" style="fill: blue" /></svg>';

var all = Snap.parse(svg);

// append the all.svg node. cool
s.append( all.node );

// get the red circle definition
var redc = all.select('#redc');

all.node.append(redc.node); // append as a child of the svg node

// foreign object
var foreign = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg',"foreignObject");
foreign.setAttribute('width', 500);
foreign.setAttribute('height', 150);
foreign.setAttribute('fill', 'pink');
var p = document.createElement('p');
foreign.appendChild(p);
var text = document.createTextNode("Hello World");
p.appendChild(text);

// add the foreign object to the correct part of the tree
all.node.append( foreign );
```

```html
<script src="http://snapsvg.io/assets/js/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```